# Is it possible to pass values to the structure variable which is already passed as parameter to the thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have created 5 threads in a pool of thread. While creating the thread pool I have passed a pointer to the structure. Now my problem is that, whenever a client will connect to server i have to copy its IP address in one of the member of that structure. After getting that IP address I have to call thread again (by using SetEvent(), because the threads are waiting for event). Is it possible or I have to think other way..? Please suggest me any Idea.

Answer (score -1):

They can be waiting (sem_wait) for a blocking Queue using semaphores. When you add some IP to the queue with sem_post and some will be awake and can get the IP from the queue.

I hope it will help

Comment: Thanks... but the threads are waiting for events... and how to implement a bloack queue... as I am new to this... plz elaborate it if possible...